# FullCalendar - Changing the URL of Google Events

Tags: fullcalendar

I've got a FullCalendar instance with multiple Google calendars displaying correctly on my site.

I'm able to disable the click action on the events to stop people from clicking through to the Google calendar link, but I was wondering if I'm able to change that link to something else? Ideally if someone clicked on an event, they'd be taken to a section lower down the page.

No matter what I seem to do though, I can't seem to change the default away from being the Google calendar link, I've tried adding a url option, that hasn't worked and I've tried a couple of the suggestions from here, but can't seem to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the eventDataTransform callback to control the properties of events, including the URL, and also the eventClick callback to control what happens when an event is clicked on

Comment: Thanks for that! Quick question, I've managed to use eventDataTransform to change the url, but I have multiple calendars imported using eventSources, is there anyway of changing the url for each specifically rather than amending all of them to be the same?

Comment: You mean a different URL per event source? So, the event object for an event from a particular a source contains a reference to that source (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object), so you could use that in eventDataTransform to help you decide.

Comment: Or perhaps the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSourceSuccess could help you instead. It's really worth having a proper long look at the documentation, as there's a lot there, and you might be able to work some of this stuff out yourself much quicker.